# How to Bypass HTTP link to HTTPS from an iframe

Tags: php, apache, http, iframe, https

I have created  one iframe in my domain, where i am calling an another website into that iframe.

So it's working fine till all the links are redirect as per http. But it is showing broken image page when it is redirecting to https server of their domain.

So can any one give me any advice what will be the best solution for this.

```
<?php 

header("access-control-allow-origin: *");
include "views/***/header.html"; 
?>

<section>
    <?php if($this->page_name=='content'){ ?>
    <div>
        <iframe  id='iframe2' src="http://content.******.com/?s=jd" frameborder="0" style="overflow: hidden; height: 900px; width: 100%;scrolling=no;"></iframe>
    </div>
  <?php }
   else if($this->page_name=='recruiter'){ ?>
    <div>
        <iframe id='iframe2' src="http://recruiter.*****.com/v2/ecom/index.html?s=jd" frameborder="0" style="overflow: hidden; height: 900px; width: 100%;scrolling=no;"></iframe>
    </div>
  <?php } ?>
</section>
<?php include "views/***/footer.html"; ?>
```

This code will not help that much because, all things are happening inside the iframe.

Comment: Hi Hassan, why do you need code for this. then also i have given the snippet check that

Comment: Are the images itself https? Some browser do not allow images being loaded from another domain/plain http while using https

Comment: No. those are not images. that is page , which should come after clicking some define link. but the link is https. so it's not able to by pass the domain.  so broken page is showing. hope u get that.

Comment: we got permission from the other party to access https link. that's it